# Azure Key Vault: The user, group, or app does not have secrets set permission on key vault

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am creating a script using Azure CLI that will automatically generate an App Registration (service principal), and then use that App Registration to create a secret that will be stored in Azure Key Vault.

However, I am getting the following error:

The user, group or application 'appid=04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46;oid=0ec2b0e8-daeb-46a8-b627-0d4f61f87157;numgroups=134;iss=https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/' does not have secrets set permission on key vault 'asakeyabcfelaqpgsfnxcy;location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287

Can anyone provide guidance on what this ID is and how to resolve this error?  This is not my App Registration Object ID or App ID.

Comment: Did you read the document at the link provided in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there're 2 points you're now concerning, one is you failed to add secret, another is the app id in the error message is not the one you registered.

I think you've followed the document to execute the cli command, so I just want to explain the second point. Pls allow me show you a code sample for a better explanation.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

public async Task<IActionResult> PrivacyAsync()
{
    var kvUri = "https://your_vault_name.vault.azure.net/";
    var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    _ = await client.SetSecretAsync("test0311", "hello");
    return View();
}
```

When we want to add key vault secret to azure, we need to provide a credential so that our operations are authenticated. This is the `DefaultAzureCredential()` here, and it has several sources to get the authentication like screenshot below.

[image]

That means if someone sets the [environment variables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#environment-variables) for authentication, then it will cover the information you entered when executing cli command, this may usually cause the issue that the app is different from what you set. I think you may follow this document to check all your configurations and try again, or you can directly add environment variables with the app you registered on your computer.

By the way, pls don't forget to [add access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-cli) in azure portal for the azure ad app you registered.

Comment: I happened to have a Azure PowerShell connection active while at the same time having to re-authenticate the Visual Studio credentials. This resulted in a weird error message, as I thought it tried to use my VS user, but actually used the PowerShell one.